# Postgres - Revoke database acess from user, but allow replication acess

Tags: replication, permissions, postgresql-9.5

The DB have a replication server, i need to revoke the permission on the user "user_bi" but allow the acess of this same user on the replication server!

```
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM user_bi; -- on master.
```

This replicate the revoke to the slave.

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM user_bi; -- on the slave.
```

This returns a error "SQL Error [25006]: ERROR: cannot execute GRANT in a read-only transaction".

- Can i revoke the permissions in only one databank ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I denied the acess by IP on the pg_hba.conf file.